# How can I make LongPressdDraggable widget which looks an icon when dragged?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface

I'm a beginner in Flutter.

I want to create a TextField widget that can be dragged when pressed long. The widget will be designed to change into an icon form when long-pressed, and to cause an event when dropped on the target.

How can I make this widget?

I just tried LongPressDraggable widget but I don't know how to change the widget to Icon widget when dragged.

Comment: Checkout this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html. Whatever you'll pass in `feedback` will displayed when you're dragging. So, you can pass Icon as well

Comment: Thank you! Next time, I will read the manual and widget parameters carefully.